# Spring Cloud Server Config only refreshing application.yml and not other properties files

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

I have a bunch of YAML and properties files in my Spring Boot project :

```
- application.yml
- application-dev.yml
- spring-integration.properties
- common.properties
- test.yml
- ...
```

I'm trying to understand how can I implement Spring Cloud Server Config for my project and I have a hard time figuring out why Spring Cloud Server Config is not picking up any of the changes on any of my other files (but `application.yml` & `application-dev.yml`).

For example, in my `spring-integration.properties`, after changing this value :

```
start.task.rate=500000
```

And `POST` to `/management/refresh`, nothing is detected by the actuator and I get an `{}` response.

However, when I change my `datasource` in `application.yml`, I get the expected result :

```
[
   "spring.datasource.url"
]
```

Here is my `Application.java` :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
@ImportResource("classpath:integration-config.xml")
@ConfigurationProperties
@EnableSwagger2
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And my bootstrap.yml :

```
spring:
  application:
    name: ${appName:tasky}
  profiles:
    include:
    - native
  cloud:
    config:
      failFast: true     
      server:
        bootstrap: true
        prefix: /config
        native:
          search-locations: file:///C:/workspace/tasky/config/
```

I'm using :

```
<spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
<spring-boot-version>1.5.9.RELEASE</spring-boot-version>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I could gathered, on /refresh Spring Actuator (?) is only picking up properties files starting with `${appName}` or `application`, in my case I had to regroup all my properties files under one file named : `tasky-{profile}.properties`.